# Proper Usage of @autoreleasepool

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-management, xcode7, nsautoreleasepool

I'm mixing some ObjectiveC and C++ in my code. (My files are `.mm` files instead of `.m`.) When is the proper reason to wrap any code block with `@autoreleasepool`? Not knowing what I'm doing, I'm wrapping any block of code that may contain any non-ObjectiveC variable, whether it be `int`, `char`, `std::string`, or any pointer thereof of a non-ObjectiveC variable. So, every class method in my C++ class has an `@autoreleasepool` wrapper inside it.

Am I doing it wrong?

> Note that on previous questions sort of related to this question, they talk about using alloc, init, and release, and these seem to be deprecated now in XCode7+. So, I need the latest advice on this, not old advice. I need advice pertaining to XCode7 or greater.

Comment: You don't have to wrap your calls in @autoreleasepool--there is one created automatically per thread. If you are on a thread that isn't the main thread you may need to create an autoreleasepool.

Comment: In any case, if you try to autorelease an object when there is no autorelease pool in place you'll get a printed warning in your console

Comment: Why, when I create a console app, does it add the @autoreleasepool block by default in the main.m it creates, then?

Comment: I think the machinery is set up by calling NSApplicationMain(). In an app your events, callouts, timers etc are invoked from the AppKit runtime which sets up an autorelease loop every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autorelease pools are for limiting the lifetimes of things that were `autorelease`d inside it. `autorelease` is a Cocoa Objective-C API, so only Objective-C code can `autorelease` things. So it would never make any sense to put an autorelease pool around a block of pure C/C++ code that you are sure never calls into Objective-C code.

Autorelease pools are usually only useful for situations where you have a loop that runs many times where each iteration may perform lots of `autorelease`. Note that not all Objective-C code will `autorelease`; it's not obvious. Some Cocoa APIs will `autorelease` and some will not. If it's all your own code written in ARC, it will probably not `autorelease`.

Comment: Okay, so if I have a C++ function, when do I need to release those variables? I'm just so afraid of memory leaks that I've heard from other programmers, and don't even know how to detect those.

Comment: @Volomike: What do you mean "release those variables"? `retain`/`release` is a Cocoa API for Objective-C objects. You cannot `retain`/`release` anything else.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AppKit, you don't have to create autorelease pools:

> The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at
>   the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the
>   end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while
>   processing an event. If you use the Application Kit, you therefore
>   typically don’t have to create your own pools. If your application
>   creates a lot of temporary autoreleased objects within the event loop,
>   however, it may be beneficial to create “local” autorelease pools to
>   help to minimize the peak memory footprint.

([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAutoreleasePool))

Comment: Just because there is one autorelease pool per iteration of the run loop doesn't mean you don't want to put your own autorelease pools in some places in your code.

Comment: true--incomplete answer. I will expand it.